# Android Calendar Provider Showing Phone's Calendar in App

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create an app that allows you to add events to your phone's calendar using this piece of code:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(calIntent);
```

Although I want the user to be able to see his calendar in my app and not have to go to the phone's app! Is there a way to show the calendar in the app or do I have to sync the phone's calendar with a calendarview? And if I have to do the latter, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your Google Calendar's data in your app, you need to use Google calendar's API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Can't I use Android Calendar Provider?

Comment: Sure, it would be easier, you can use it by calling query insert, delete statements instead of learning the google api specification.

Comment: I'm already using it to create the event, but how do I get the calendar on my app?